# Why does import $ from 'jquery'; remove .modal() from $()?

Tags: bootstrap-modal, reactjs

I have a react application that I inject into a bootstrap modal like so:

```
let provider =
    <Provider store={store}>
        <MyElem />
    </Provider>;
let elem = document.getElementById(Constants.APP_ELEMENT_ID);
ReactDOM.render(provider, elem);

$('#btn_banana').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(elem).modal();
});
```

I originally had `import $ from 'jquery';` the following at the top of the JSX and I would get the following error:

> vendor-attributes.jsx?f269c41…:72 Uncaught TypeError: (0 , _jquery2.default)(...).modal is not a function(…)

The actual transpiled javascript the browser was executing is:

> (0, _jquery2.default)(elem).modal();

Removing that import line made the modal display with the React application and changed the transpiled JavaScript to `$(elem).modal();`.

Why did adding the import function break that and is there a way to add another import function instead of removing that one?

Comment: Well I'm guessing because the imported version doesn't have bootsrap's `modal` function added to jquery's prototype, where as the one you've probably included in a script tag does. Why do you want a local copy if you already have a global one?

Comment: @azium well I guess when you put it that way, I'm never going to assume jquery isn't global

Comment: well I wouldn't go that far. if you were nervous about it you could do something like `if (!window.jQuery) var $ = require('jquery')` but you would have to add bootstrap methods after that. My general advice is drop jquery and bootstrap altogether and just use react :p

Comment: @azium in the reality of this app, I can assume bootstrap and jquery will always be here, and when there not I'll adjust my imports.